# Creating database with a relative path

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am supposed to be testing a piece of software that uses mssql express as the backend for data storage. When it is creating its databases, it tries to create them in my home directory that is on a network share, which does not work. I.e. it does

```
create database [db] on primary (name=N'db' filename=N'g:\my docs\app\db\db.mdf' ...
```

and a bunch more of parameters.

I tried to disconnect the computer from the network, then it tried to run

```
create database [db] on primary (name=N'db' filename=N'\app\db\db.mdf' ...
```

which also did not work.

Basically my question is then: How can I convince mssql express to use another base directory when creating new files?

Comment: Posting error messages would help. For network share: the user running the SQL Service surely has no drive mapping g: (and a database on a Network share is ... not the best idea) for relative paths: they don't work, transact SQL wants an absolute path. But if you give him an absolute path, where the directories already exist it will work.

Comment: Tom: Rather Mssql express that failed..

Answer (score 1):

The software installer is reading the `%userprofile%` or `%homepath%` environment variables to create the user database, you will have to change the installation script or temporary change the environment variables while running the installer.

This has nothing to do with Express itself as it is creating the databases where it's asked to do so by the installation script. 
Now if you want to have the database in the home directory you are better off by using [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx). I would consider this software a failure.

Comment: Hmmm... Now now I have reinstalled sql express with homedrive set to c:, homepath is \users\mortens userprofile is c:\users\mortens, but still is sqlexpress not able to create a database when given a relative path...

Comment: Under which user account is the SQL Express service running as, does that user have permissions on the directory where you want to install the files ?